# how to distribute batch mode jobs to individual boards running linux mounted over NFS

Tags: linux, batch-processing, nfs

Few boards running linux kernel with common root file system mounted over NFS.
A file, in NFS mounted file system, holds the job description to be run in batch mode.

Each line in the File holds one job.
How to distribute the jobs evenly among the boards.

Any sample code or references is useful..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install a resource manager/job scheduler such as [Slurm](http://slurm.schedmd.com/) or [Condor](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/). Such tool allows you to submit jobs, described by a shell script, to several computers and handle  load balancing, input/output management, etc.